# HTML: Width for a td independent of the upper tr?

Tags: html

if i have a table like following, I didn't make it to define a special width for a single  element. Is this possible?

For illustration, i've tried it like this:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Bla</td>
        <td>_____________________________________________________</td>
        <td>Bla2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Blub</td>
        <td style="width: 100px;">Bli</td>
        <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That's not how a table works.

Comment: @BoltClock so do you mean there is no possibility to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this possible?

Not really, no. The only thing that exists is the `colspan` and `rowspan` attributes that can make a cell span across two columns like so:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Bla</td>
        <td>_____________________________________________________</td>
        <td>Bla2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Blub Bli - I will span across the whole large line!</td>
        <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

but the exact thing that you want - being completely flexible in cell widths - can be achieved only by two separate tables.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not specified width explicitly, your other TDs will also be as large as the largest one:

```
<td>_____________________________________________________</td>
```

Same is the case with `table` tag because you have not set width for it too.